# Custom Shipping Method Error

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento. The Magento version that i am working on is 1.9.2.2. I created a custom shipping method using [this](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/14/magento-create-custom-shipping-method/) tutorial. I have made some changes to it in order to suit my needs. The problem is i get this error on the last step of checkout page

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getShp_carrier() on a
>   non-object in
>   ../app/code/local/Excellence/Pickup/Model/Sales/Order.php on line 12

I have googled a lot on this problem and found two links [1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62953/magento-custom-shipping-module-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-setstore) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492459/magento-custom-shipping-module-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-setstore) relevant to my problem but that didn't help. Here is my **config.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Excellence_Pickup>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Excellence_Pickup>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <pickup>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Excellence_Pickup</module>
                <frontName>pickup</frontName>
            </args>
        </pickup>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <pickup>
                <file>pickup.xml</file>
            </pickup>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
    <events>
        <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
            <observers>
                <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>pickup/observer</class>
                    <method>saveShippingMethod</method>
                </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
            </observers>
        </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
            <observers>
                <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>pickup/observer</class>
                    <method>saveOrderAfter</method>
                </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
        <sales_order_load_after>
            <observers>
                <sales_order_load_after>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>pickup/observer</class>
                    <method>loadOrderAfter</method>
                </sales_order_load_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_load_after>
        <sales_quote_load_after>
            <observers>
                <sales_quote_load_after>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>pickup/observer</class>
                    <method>loadQuoteAfter</method>
                </sales_quote_load_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_load_after>
    </events>
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order>Excellence_Pickup_Model_Sales_Order</order>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
        <pickup>
            <class>Excellence_Pickup_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>pickup_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </pickup>
        <pickup_mysql4>
            <class>Excellence_Pickup_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <pickup>
                    <table>order_shipping_pickup</table>
                </pickup>
            </entities>
        </pickup_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <pickup_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Excellence_Pickup</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </pickup_setup>
        <pickup_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </pickup_write>
        <pickup_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </pickup_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <pickup>
            <class>Excellence_Pickup_Block</class>
        </pickup>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <pickup>
            <class>Excellence_Pickup_Helper</class>
        </pickup>
    </helpers>
</global>
<default>
    <carriers>
        <pickup>
           <active>1</active>
            <model>Excellence_Pickup_Model_Carrier_Pickup</model>
           <title>Self Pickup</title>
           <name>Store Pickup</name>
           <price>0</price>
           <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
        </pickup>
     </carriers>
   </default>
```

**app\code\local\Excellence\Pickup\Model\Carrier\Pickup.php** file

```
<?php

class Excellence_Pickup_Model_Carrier_Pickup extends 
Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface {

protected $_code = 'pickup';

public function getFormBlock(){
    return 'pickup/pickup';
}

public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')) {
        return false;
    }

    $handling = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/handling');
    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    $show = true;
    if($show){ // This if condition is just to demonstrate how to return success and error in shipping methods

        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        $method->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
        $method->setCost($this->getConfigData('price'));
        $result->append($method);

    }else{
        $error = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
        $error->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        $error->setErrorMessage($this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'));
        $result->append($error);
    }
    return $result;
}
public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    return array('excellence'=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
}
}
```

**app\code\local\Excellence\Pickup\Model\Sales\Order.php** file

```
<?php


class Excellence_Pickup_Model_Sales_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order{

public function getShippingDescription(){
    $desc = parent::getShippingDescription();
   $pickupObject = $this->getPickupObject();

    if(strpos($desc, 'Customer Shipping Account') !== false){

        $desc.= " | Carrier:".$pickupObject->getShp_carrier()." Via ".$pickupObject->getShp_method()."  | Account No:".$pickupObject->getAccountno();

         }
        return $desc;

     }



}
```

**app\code\local\Excellence\Pickup\Model\Observer.php** file

```
<?php
class Excellence_Pickup_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object
{
public function saveShippingMethod($evt){
    $request = $evt->getRequest();
    $quote = $evt->getQuote();
    $pickup = $request->getParam('shipping_pickup',false);
    $quote_id = $quote->getId();
    $data = array($quote_id => $pickup);
    if($pickup){
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setPickup($data);
    }
    //print_r($data);die;
}
public function saveOrderAfter($evt){
    $order = $evt->getOrder();
    $quote = $evt->getQuote();
    $quote_id = $quote->getId();
    $pickup = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getPickup();
    if(isset($pickup[$quote_id])){
        $data = $pickup[$quote_id];
        $data['order_id'] = $order->getId();
        $pickupModel = Mage::getModel('pickup/pickup');
        $pickupModel->setData($data);
        $pickupModel->save();
    }
}
public function loadOrderAfter($evt){
    $order = $evt->getOrder();
    if($order->getId()){
        $order_id = $order->getId();
        $pickupCollection = Mage::getModel('pickup/pickup')->getCollection();
        $pickupCollection->addFieldToFilter('order_id',$order_id);
        $pickup = $pickupCollection->getFirstItem();
        $order->setPickupObject($pickup);
    }
}   
public function loadQuoteAfter($evt)
{
    $quote = $evt->getQuote();
    if($quote->getId()){
        $quote_id = $quote->getId();
        $pickup = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getPickup();
        if(isset($pickup[$quote_id])){
            $data = $pickup[$quote_id];
            $quote->setPickupData($data);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What it `getPickupObject` function in your code? I think you are using a function which is not defined in your code.

Comment: actually i have followed [this](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/07/magento-advanced-shipping-method-development/) tutorial and took the code as it is. May be that's why i am unable to fix this bug.

Comment: If you have created all the files then there should be no error in your code. The object is set in `loadOrderAfter` function, did you create this function in your code?

Comment: Yes i have, I am updating the question so that you can see that file also

Comment: Did you add `shp_carrier`, `shp_method` and `accountno` fields in your `order_shipping_pickup` table?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya yes and they are getting populated just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here, `pickObject` is the object of the collection which will get data from your table.

Please add `shp_carrier`, `shp_method` and `accountno` fields in your `order_shipping_pickup` table.

Once you add the fields after that you will be able to get the data.

You can see below code where the module is trying to get pickup data using order id,

```
$pickupCollection = Mage::getModel('pickup/pickup')->getCollection();
$pickupCollection->addFieldToFilter('order_id',$order_id);
$pickup = $pickupCollection->getFirstItem();
$order->setPickupObject($pickup);
```

Please confirm with your database if you have a record in your table with current order id.

Also, you need to check if the object is available before using it in your `getShippingDescription` function.

```
if(strpos($desc, 'Customer Shipping Account') !== false && $pickupObject){
    $desc.= " | Carrier:".$pickupObject->getShpCarrier()." Via ".$pickupObject->getShpMethod()."  | Account No:".$pickupObject->getAccountno();
 }
```

Comment: Just added this line to my code and every thing runs smoothly.. if(strpos($desc, 'Customer Shipping Account') !== false && $pickupObject)